# How can I use Chrome Remote Desktop to access dual monitors at the host site and dual monitors at the local site?

Tags: google-chrome

My employees have 2 monitors at work.  Now they are working from home.  One employee has a newer Dell laptop and the other employee has an older Mac laptop.  I want them to be able to add a second monitor at home so they can take advantage of the 2 monitors that they have at their desk in the office  We use Chrome Remote Desktop to connect.  I am told that this is workable but I cannot figure out how to do it.  Can you help?   Thank you.